# Google maps zoom level issue

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

Hi I need zoom level smaller for about 7. I have no idea how to do that. I tried with:

> &z=nn
>
> &zoom=nn
>
> &amp&z=nn
>
> &amp&zoom=nn

on the end of 'src'.

I tried to generate new link but no luck.
Google still changes their API, it's annoying!

Can you tell me how can I edit this link? I'm tired of this...

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2529.6639512822785!2d18.381542775115953!3d50.651931916518464!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4710e498479500df%3A0xad4e377e0c5d0e61!2sDarkas.+FHU!5e0!3m2!1spl!2sse!4v1415788568014" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start)

Entering: "Firma Handlowo-Usługowa DARKAS" in the wizard gives me this:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJ3wCVR5jkEEcRYQ5dDH43Tq0
&key=..." allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

According to the [embedded map documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#optional_parameters), the following optional parameters are allowed:

> **Optional parameters**
>
> The following optional parameters can be used with any of the map modes listed above.
>
> - **center** defines the center of the map view. It accepts a comma-separated latitude and longitude value (such as 37.4218,-122.0840).
> - **zoom** sets the initial zoom level of the map. Accepted values range from 0 (the whole world) to 21 (individual buildings). The upper limit can vary depending on the map data available at the selected location.
> - **maptype** can be either roadmap (the default) or satellite, and defines the type of map tiles to load.
> - **language** defines the language to use for UI elements and for the display of labels on map tiles. Note that this parameter is only supported for some country tiles; if the specific language requested is not supported for the tile set, then the default language for that tileset will be used. By default, visitors will see a map in their own language.
> - **region** defines the appropriate borders and labels to display, based on geo-political sensitivities. Accepts a region code specified as a two-character ccTLD (top-level domain) value.

[live example](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_20160222.html) (with zoom=18)